# Make bullets fire outwards in a circle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a player that when the user taps I want to be able to spawn 8 bullets around the player (with a 45˚ separation between them) and proceed to move them outwards to the edge of the screen.

The circle from where the bullets originate from is correct, but the bullets in the bottom left of the screen seem to be moving faster than the ones in the top right. Also the bullets are facing sideways, not pointing outwards.

```
func fireSpecialWeapon() {

    stride(from: 0, to: 2 * CGFloat.pi, by: 2 * CGFloat.pi / 10 ).forEach { angle in
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bulletCircle")
        bullet.setScale(3)
        bullet.zRotation = angle
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.zPosition = 2
        //move outwards to the edge of the screen
        let distance: CGFloat = 2000
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: distance * cos(angle), y: distance * sin(angle))
        let move = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)

        self.addChild(bullet)
        bullet.run(move)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code doing? You didn’t say if it worked or not. You only said it was tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use trig to figure out the end point based on the angle.  distance * sin is the y component and distance * cos is the x component.  The code looks somethign like this:

```
stride(from: 0, to: 2 * CGFloat.pi, by: 2 * CGFloat.pi / 8).forEach { angle in
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bulletCircle")
    bullet.setScale(3)
    bullet.zRotation = angle
    bullet.position = player.position
    bullet.zPosition = 2
    //move outwards to the edge of the screen
    let distance: CGFloat = 500
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: distance * cos(angle), y: distance * sin(angle))
    let move = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)

    self.addChild(bullet)
    bullet.run(move)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've changed the code and have tried to explain whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that your rotation calculation is not correct.

First the rotation of each bullet should be pi / 4 from its neighbours.

So you should not use `pi / I` but `(pi / 4) * I`.

That should fix up the rotation but I’m not sure if that’s everything that’s not working.

Comment: The `moveBy` won't work in this case. For the bullets moving only vertically (i.e the ones spawning at 0˚ and 180˚) telling them to move 500 for X will move them sideways.

Comment: @JackRichards I’m like 99% certain that it would move in the bullet node’s space and not its parents space. Since the bullet node is rotated, so is its space. So moving it by only x will actually move it forwards relative to its rotation. Will have to check. Brb